# In the constructive theory of direct categories, is it decidable whether an arbitrary morphism is an identity or not?

Tags: ct.category-theory, constructive-mathematics, ordinal-numbers

I'm wondering what the legit definition of direct categories should be in constructive mathematics. I must admit I don't even know in what literature I should look for the definition. I would appreciate any assistance you can provide.

Let $D$ be a quiver (a category without identities or compositions -- i.e. directed graph). For the purpose of this question, we say $D$ is a *direct* quiver if it satisfies the following equivalent conditions:

- For any objects $x, y \in \operatorname{Ob}(D)$, write $x < y$ if there is a morphism $x \to y$. Then $<$ is a well-founded relation on $\operatorname{Ob}(D)$.
- There exists a function $d\colon \operatorname{Ob}(D) \to \mathrm{Ord}$, where $\mathrm{Ord}$ is the class of all ordinals, satisfying $d(x) < d(y)$ for each morphism $x \to y$.
- There exist a set (or class if $D$ is permitted to be large) $W$, a well-order $<$ on $W$, and a function $d\colon \operatorname{Ob}(D) \to W$ satisfying $d(x) < d(y)$ for each morphism $x\to y$.

If $D$ is a semicategory (i.e. a quiver equipped with associative compositions or a category without the assumption of identities), we consider $D$ to be a *direct* semicategory if $D$ is a direct quiver.

My question is: which of the following, or what else, is (or should be) conventionally used as a *constructive* definition of direct categories? Let $D$ be a category.

1. We say $D$ is direct if the quiver obtained by removing all the identity morphisms from $D$ is direct.
2. We say $D$ is direct if it is obtained by freely adjoining identities to a direct semicategory.
3. (Vague) We say $D$ is direct if the "wide" subquiver of $D$ spanned by all the morphisms distinguished from identities is direct. Here, the distinction of a morphism from identities should be separately defined; it could be an apartness relation satisfying some conditions, but there could be something better.

Conditions 1 and 2 are different in that Condition 2 implies the dichotomy of whether a morphism is identity or not, while Condition 1 doesn't. Which definition should be adopted when referring to direct categories?

My confusion began when I looked up nlab for the definition of direct categories. According to the [nlab article for direct category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/direct+category), the followings are both equivalent conditions for the directness of $D$:

4. There exists a function $d\colon \operatorname{Ob}(D)\to\mathrm{Ord}$, where
   $\mathrm{Ord}$ is the class of ordinals, such that every nonidentity morphism of
   $D$ raises the degree.
5. There exists an identity-reflecting functor (that is, it maps a morphism to an identity if and only if the morphism is itself an identity) $d\colon D\to\mathbf{Ord}$, where $\mathbf{Ord}$ is the large poset of ordinals viewed as a category.

Condition 4 is equivalent to Condition 1. Condition 5 needs clarification in the definition of the category $\mathbf{Ord}$, but I guess it is equivalent to the condition 2. In order for the condition 5 to work, the non-identity part of the category $\mathbf{Ord}$ should itself be a well-ordered class. In constructive setting, $x < y \overset{\mathrm{def}}{\iff} x \subsetneq y$ cannot be shown to be a well-order; it should be $x < y \overset{\mathrm{def}}{\iff} x \in y$. If you make it a reflexive poset, the only sensible choice I can think of is $x \leq y \overset{\mathrm{def}}{\iff} x = y \mathrel\vee x \in y$. From this rather unnatural construction of the category $\mathbf{Ord}$, Condition 5 is shown to be equivalent to Condition 2.

We could do inductive argument on $\operatorname{Ob}(D)$ solely with Condition 1, but the dichotomy from Condition 2 is quite useful. The prototypical direct category $\mathbf{Ord}$ in Condition 5 satisfies Condition 2; therefore the additional assumption in Condition 2 might not be too strong, but I'm not sure at all. Furthermore, if you go on to the Reedy category theory along the line of Condition 2, it would demand that the degree-lowering/degree-raising part of the Reedy category should be decidable subsets of the collection of all morphisms, which sounds too strict, but again I'm not sure (I'm just saying it "sounds" strict, I don't know how to test if the definition is too strong).

I'm not familiar with constructive mathematics. In fact, I just need a good definition to write in my paper. It will use *finite* direct categories for syntactical matters. I say a category/semicategory/quiver $C$ is finite if there exists a pair of natural numbers $m,n$ and bijections $\operatorname{Ob}(C)\cong \left\{0,1,\ldots,m-1\right\}$ and $\operatorname{Mor}(C)\cong\left\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\right\}$. In this case, the equalities of morphisms and objects are decidable and hence the distinction between Conditions 1 and 2 vanishes. I just thought I would be better if I can keep my argument within finitism and at the same time discuss with decent generality where finiteness is unnecessary. I'd find any literature and explanation helpful.

Comment: These finite direct categories, will they naturally also have decidable equality of morphisms? (Also, $\mathbf{Ord}$ is not well-behaved constructively, so you should probably look at the other options first.)

Comment: The point of direct categories is almost always to be able to do proof by induction on height, so you really want this height function to ordinals to be available. The constructive theory of ordinal is a mess (By that I mean there are many non-equivalent definitions of ordinals), so if this is an option to you I would absolutely suggest to restrict to finite direct categories, so this height functions $h$ takes values in $\mathbb{N}$. This will indeed force identities to be decidable, as an arrow is an identity if and only if $h(t(f)) = h(s(f))$.

Comment: I should add that if the finite case is enough for you, then you probably should take finite to mean "finite and decidable", so that equality of arrows and objects are both decidable. If the finite-decidable case isn't enough, I would start by making a list of the properties you need for the application you have in mind and build the "correct" notion from there: there is going to be many non-equivalent definition possible and no reasons to prefer one over another in general

Comment: @SimonHenry I would have said that the point of direct categories is to do induction.  It doesn't have to be induction on ordinals, so you don't need an ordinal-valued height; all you need is a well-founded relation to do well-founded induction.

Comment: I agree. The reason I said that is that I tend to think that defining the "height" is the sort of thing you should be able to do by induction. But given that it is higly dependent on which theory of ordinal you are using, I agree this isn't the all story.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Yes, I added that explicitly in my question text.

Comment: @SimonHenry Finite direct categories would be more than enough for my syntactic construction, but my construction needs some categorical preparation, and these categorical preparation would be applicable to infinite ones. In fact, I, at least for now, assume my argument would be doable with Condition 1, but the discussion would surely be more intricate than with Condition 2, so I thought it would be easier if I could stick with Condition 2.

Comment: @SimonHenry: *"The constructive theory of ordinal is a mess (By that I mean there are many non-equivalent definitions of ordinals),"*.  As you know as a constructive mathematician, classical definitions *usually* bifurcate intuitionistically. Naming properties of the ordinals that you like as if you're doing "pick and mix" in a sweet shop is not going to result in coherent mathematics.  I have just completed a draft of a categorical technique for considering it systematically. See *Ordinals and Coalgebras* on http://paultaylor.eu/ordinals/

Comment: The most general constructive notion of ordinal is a well-founded transitive relation.  Any well-founded relation has an ordinal rank in this sense, defined straightforwardly by well-founded induction.  But, again, often it's better to just do induction directly on the well-founded relation rather than the ordinal rank.

Comment: I don't like your definition of the order relation on $\mathbf{Ord}$, and I would not treat (5) as equivalent to (2). I agree that you need $x<y$ to mean $x\in y$, but then $x\leq y$ should mean $x\subseteq y$. So equality of ordinals is not decidable, and consequently, it's not decidable whether a morphism in a (5)-directed category is an identity.

Comment: *(5)-direct (not ‘directed’)

Comment: @TobyBartels With your definition of $\le$, I don't think $\mathbf{Ord}$ ensures any kind of induction (Oh but I now realize this is a wild guess; I don't know a proof for this). The point of direct categories is induction on objects, which I prioritized. When the poset $\mathbf{Ord}$ is seen as a category, its morphisms are determined by $\le$. So an identity-reflecting functor $F\colon D \to \mathbf{Ord}$ only requires $x \to y \Rightarrow F(x) \subseteq F(y)$ and $F(x) = F(y), f\colon x \to y \Rightarrow x=y, f=id$. A non-identity $x\to y$ only requires $F(x) \subsetneq F(y)$.

Comment: Induction isn't about $\leq$ at all; it's about $<$.  In (5), $\leq$ is needed for the functor from $D$.  But to do induction constructively, you say that if something is true for $x$ whenever it's true for all $y < x$, then it's true for all $x$; so $\leq$ doesn't play a role there.

Comment: @TonyBartels We need the induction of $\left[\forall x,\left[\forall y, \forall f\colon y\to x, f \neq id \Rightarrow P(y)\right]\Rightarrow P(x)\right] \Rightarrow \forall x, P(x)$ on objects. And $f\colon y\to x, f \neq id$ only ensures $F(x) \lneq F(y)$. I think, in order to make your argument work, some "distinction" of morphism from identities should be there, and Condition 5 should be tweaked from identity-reflecting to distinction-preserving, along the line of Condition 3. If you would kindly continue this, why not we move to chat?

Comment: @TonyBartels I looked up in meta and found this: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/246/please-avoid-extended-discussions-in-comments According to this, the Stack Exchange system says "please avoid extended discussion in comments," but it is not prohibited in MathOverflow, so if you don't mind would you continue here?

Comment: Yeah, there are more comments in MO than on SE itself, especially under questions. I can do the discussion wherever you like, as long as I get notified about it. (But I almost didn't see these replies since you misspelt my @. In contrast, you should get notified to any comments under your own question.)

Comment: My main objection to (5) isn't that it's the right way to do things (although I think that it could be done; I'll come back to that), but that it has a bad way to set up $\mathbf{Ord}$. So I'm defending the honour of $\mathbf{Ord}$, if you will, especially in light of Andrej's first comment here that $\mathbf{Ord}$ is badly behaved (which is true for your $\mathbf{Ord}$ but not for mine). If (5) still isn't as good as (2), then so be it; but it's different and should be a separate item on the list of options.

Comment: Anyway, you can organize the induction using (5) because (5) gives you the positive notion of distinction that you want to make the vague option (3) work: we say that $y<x$ iff $d(y)\in d(x)$, and then $f\colon y\to x$ is a non-identity iff $y<x$. (We already know that any endomorphism must be an identity since that's how it is in $\mathbf{Ord}$.) Or to write it all out explicitly, the principle of induction is $[\forall x,[\forall y,d(y)\,{\in}\,d(x)\Rightarrow\forall f\colon y\,{\to}\,x,P(y)]\Rightarrow P(x)]\Rightarrow \forall x,P(x)$.

Comment: @TobyBartels $f\colon y \to x$ is a non-identity iff $d(y) \in d(x)$: I think I have a counter-example to this. $\mathrm{id}\colon \mathbf{Ord} \to \mathbf{Ord}$ is an identity-reflecting functor since it is identity, but in this case you are stating that $y \subseteq x$ implies that $y \neq x \Leftrightarrow y \in x$.

Comment: I'm exactly *not* stating that. In (3), you note that, instead of using $\neg\,(f=\mathrm{id})$, you could use some kind of apartness-like relation instead, and my point is that (5) (with my interpretation of $\mathbf{Ord}$) gives us that relation. So use $d(y)\in d(x)$ *instead* of using $\neg\,(y=x)$ (in a context where we already have $f\colon y\to x$); I agree that these are not equivalent, and the first one (which is stronger) is better (because you can do induction on it).

Comment: Oh, I thought you said "we say that $y<x$ iff $d(y) \in d(x)$ and then (it holds that) $f\colon y \to x$ is a non-identity iff $y<x$," which, of course, is not the case. you said "we say that $y<x$ iff $d(y) \in d(x)$ and (also that) then $f\colon y \to x$ is a non-identity iff $y<x$."

Comment: My next question is: would the condition of the degree functor reflecting identity be enough? I mean, identity-reflection is classically a very strong condition, because we can do well-founded induction with all the non-identity morphisms. However, constructively, identity-reflection assures nothing about how many distinguished morphisms there are. I'd like even to ask if the condition of reflecting identities is of any use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe (2) is the best definition.  Consider what you want to do with a direct category: you want to construct presheaves and natural transformations between them inductively, assuming that they are already constructed for all $x<y$ and then constructing them for $y$.  But then you have to construct them (or prove them to be natural) for all morphisms too.  Your inductive hypothesis shows you how to deal with morphisms that strictly raise degree, and of course you can deal with identities; but if you don't know that all morphisms fall into one of these two classes (which is what (2) tells you), for a general morphism you are stuck.

My preprint [Reedy categories and their generalizations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.01065) includes a definition of direct categories (or their opposites, inverse categories) as those obtained from the empty category by successively taking collages along profunctors to discrete sets.  Since a collage has decidable identities on the newly added objects, this should be constructively equivalent to definition (2).  This definition is also nicely adapted to inductive constructions, as shown in the paper.

Comment: Why doesn't (5) work? (With the understanding in my comment under the question that (5) is weaker than (2).) You don't need to show that every morphism is either an identity or a rank-raising one, if you can show that all morphisms are covered; and you can do this by induction on the rank of the target. (Although it still might be better to think of this as inducting directly on the objects.)

Comment: I don't see how to do it by induction on the rank of the target; it seems to me that the inductive hypothesis only applies to rank-raising morphisms.

Comment: If you want to prove some predicate $P$ for every morphism $f\colon\sigma f\to\tau f$ in $D$ (of which a special case is proving that something's true for every object in $D$), you could do this by proving $Q[\alpha]:\equiv\forall f,d(\tau f)\,{=}\,\alpha\Rightarrow P[f]$, which might be done by induction in $\mathrm{Ord}$. And you'd do this by proving $\forall\alpha,(\forall\beta,\beta\,{\in}\,\alpha\Rightarrow Q[\beta])\Rightarrow Q[\alpha]$, which means …

Comment: … $\forall\alpha,(\forall\beta,\beta\,{\in}\,\alpha\Rightarrow\forall g,d(\tau g)\,{=}\,\beta\Rightarrow P[g])\Rightarrow\forall f,d(\tau f)\,{=}\,\alpha\Rightarrow P[f]$. (I'm following the questioner by using $\in$ and $\subseteq$, as for von Neumann ordinals, to avoid conflict with any other order relations one might define on $\mathrm{Ord}$.) And this is equivalent to $\forall f,\forall\alpha,\alpha\,{=}\,d(\tau f)\Rightarrow(\forall g,\forall\beta,\beta\,{=}\,d(\tau g)\Rightarrow\beta\,{\in}\,\alpha\Rightarrow P[g])\Rightarrow P[f]$, which can be simplified to …

Comment: … $\forall f,(\forall g,d(\tau g)\,{\in}\,d(\tau f)\Rightarrow P[g])\Rightarrow P[f]$. Now by defining $x<y$ to mean $d(x)\in d(y)$, this can be written $\forall f,(\forall g,\tau g\,{<}\,\tau f\Rightarrow P[g])\Rightarrow P[f]$. If you can prove that, then you've proved that $P$ holds for all morphisms in $D$, by induction on the rank of the target. Or by thinking of $<$, just call it induction on the target. But nowhere does this involve decidability of being an identity.

Comment: Although now that I write that out, I see that you could just as well induct on the source. Or if you're just proving something for all objects, induct on the objects themselves. The bottom line is that $d$ pulls $\in$ back from $\mathrm{Ord}$ to a well-founded relation $<$ on the objects.

Comment: @TobyBartels Indeed.  But my point is that, in the sorts of applications we usually see of induction on direct categories, you *can't* prove that without knowing either that $f$ is an identity or that the *source* of $f$ is $<$ its target.

Comment: Let me try to be more explicit, to test my understanding of your answer, @MikeShulman. In order to define a $V$-valued presheaf $F: D^{\mathrm{op}} \to V$, for each $d \in \operatorname{Ob}(D)$, we (i) construct $F(d)$, (ii) construct $F(f)\colon F(d) \to F(d')$ for each $d' \in D$ and $f\colon d' \to d$, and (iii) prove $F(f\circ g) = F(g)\circ F(f)$  for each $d', d'' \in D$ and $g\colon d'' \to d'$ and $f\colon d'\to d$.  If we do this by induction on $d \in D$, at the time we do (ii), we have only constructed $F(d')$ for $d' < d$ or $d = d'$ and we're stuck.

Comment: (Formally speaking, if my explanation is the only problem, it would be avoided by performing three inductions, once each for (i), (ii), and (iii). But it is often the case that the construction in (i) relies on the earlier construction of (ii), so the proof must be done in one induction as a whole.)

Comment: @gksato Yes, I think that's about right.

Comment: @MikeShulman : I see. Of course, it could still work if (ii) can be deferred to a later stage even if not the end (for example, if we construct $F(f)$ for each $f\colon d''\to d'$ with $d'<d$, and add a step to check that all constructions of $F(f)$ agree since now there's some overlap). But I don't know any examples where that works.

Comment: Indeed, I agree that the direct categories that I know all have decidable equality or are just well-ordered posets. Still, if direct categories are supposed to be a categorification of well-ordered sets, then at least there's a constructive definition that covers both of these, even if the examples all bifurcate (leading to two separate lists of theorems with separate styles of proof).

Comment: Accepted because I'm already convinced by this answer, and the acceptance would be undone anytime. I randomly thought that since the notion of well-ordered sets is all about $<$, not about $\le$, the correct categorification of that concept would be direct semicategories, not any concept of direct categories I defined in my question text. Maybe, the good point about (2) is that the condition is equivalent to direct semicategories and that it defines categories.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer and great reference, @MikeShulman. I decided to leave the definition as (2) in my paper at least for now, until I find some more convincing argument.

Comment: I agree -- the categorification of a well-ordered set should really be a direct *semicategory*, and if we really want a category then we have to make it one as in (2).  This definition also covers all "well-ordered posets", because a " well-ordered poset" is not a poset in the usual sense of a reflexive relation $\le$, but defined in terms of an irreflexive relation $<$.  It's true that many constructive "well-ordered posets", like Ord, *also* have a $\le$ that isn't defined as $(x<y)\vee (x=y)$, but this relation is irrelevant to the well-orderedness.

Comment: One can axiomatize the notion of a set equipped with both $<$ and $\le$ and their relationship to each other, see e.g. theorem 8.3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.07518.  Similarly, one could try to axiomatize the notion of a set equipped with both the structure of a semicategory and a category, and their relation to each other.  Then imposing directedness of the semicategory would give a notion of "direct category" that includes both irreflexive and reflexive structure.  But I can't think of any use for them, since we can only induct on the irreflexive part.

Comment: Interestingly, in the case of Ord, the relation $\le$ can be defined in terms of $<$ in a different way: $(y\le z) = \forall x. ((x<y) \to (x<z))$.  I don't know whether that could be categorified; it feels a little bit like defining a "co-free" category generated by a semicategory.

Comment: @MikeShulman : It's not just in the case of $\mathrm{Ord}$; this applies to *any* well-ordered set. (Of course, you could define a different $\leq$ as well, but every well-ordered set comes equipped with this $\leq$ and so is a poset (and that's what I would call a ‘well-ordered poset’, keeping in mind that constructively the well order is actually a structure and not a mere property). Although only the plump ones satisfy the fifth requirement of the antithesis interpretation from your Theorem 8.3.)

Answer (score 4):

To ask whether it is decidable if a morphism is an identity is the wrong question here. In any more general setting the answer to this ought to be "no", however, here we don't have any non-identity automorphisms. Thus, the actual question is:

*Is equality of objects decidable?*

The answer to this will depend on where your directed categories are coming from and what you want to do with them. If you are in a setting where equality of objects is not decidable, you probably should work with the quiver+composition instead of the directed category (just like partial orders tend to work a bit nicer than quasiorders without decidable equality).

What needs more caution is, as Simon Henry points out, how to handle the well-foundedness.